# Explicit configuration for Eclipse Ooomph in eclipse.ini useful?

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, oomph

I've recently upgraded my Eclipse to 2023-06. Then I examined my eclipse.ini which has been used for more than a year and multiple updated versions of Eclipse. I found two lines of oomph configuration:

```
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

I probably previously copied them from somewhere but no longer remember why. So, questions:

1. What do they do? Or how do they make things different from the default behavior?
2. Are they still necessary or useful for the newest version of Eclipse, i.e. 2023-06?
3. In genera where can one find documentation and usage of these configuration parameters?

Comment: Do a web search without the `-D` prefix: see [`oomph.update.url`](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1109150&goto=1845142&#msg_1845142) and [`oomph.redirection.index.redirection`](https://github.com/a-langer/eclipse-oomph-console#settings). The `eclipse.ini` will be updated as well and is not recommended to be edited.